# spring cloud config versioning

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have all the common properties in application.properties file. version specific properties are in version1 and version2 folders in github.

```
order-service(base folder)
    application.properties
    version1
        app-dev.properties
    version2
        app-dev.properties
```

How can I set the config in application.yml file to ensure cloud config server returns version 1 props along with with common props when version1 url is hit.Below is the config that I have now to fetch props from base folder and how could it be modified to achieve the above.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.company.com/orders-properties
          username: orders
          password: orders
          search-paths: order-service
```

Comment: the prop files are environment/profile specific not version. Are both your version urls on the same jar file.... I donot think you can load the properties file based on url... if v1 and v2 are seperate jars then the jar/service name can be used to have sepearete prop file for seperate versions.

Comment: @Grinish : If I have separate jar files each having a specific version , can  I have the setup defined above? In this scenario I  would like cloud config server to return application.properties +  app-dev.properties under version 1 folder when requested from version 1 url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly this is what you need.

Lets say you have two apps called **app-dev-v1** and **app-dev-v2**.

You need to add a bootstrap.yml file inside the resources folder and add this property on both the apps.

*For app-dev-v1*

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app-dev-v1
```

*For app-dev-v2*

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app-dev-v2
```

In the repository you can have a .yml or .properties file like this inside version1 and version2 folder.

**app-dev-v1.yml** and **app-dev-v2.yml**

Also for config server you need to add the search paths:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.company.com/orders-properties
          username: orders
          password: orders
          search-paths: order-service,version*
```

Comment: Thanks @Grinish. If I am trying to test this using advanced rest client , what is the rest endpoint that I should use? I was using this endpoint earlier - http://localhost:8080/order-service/dev

Comment: I was able to access this using localhost:8080/order-service/dev-version1. Thank You.

Comment: accessing via url localhost:8080/order-service/dev-version1 seemed to work yesterday. However I am unable to see the results now. Is there a different url that I need to use?

Comment: what are you trying to access? The properties file through a url.

Comment: Yes , I am trying to access the property file through a cloud config server's url. I am looking for version directory to be treated as a profile.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong.. but if it was working yesterday then you need to see what changed between today and yesterday... also when you start the service it should tell you what properties file it is picking so that should help you too.

Comment: thank you. I am not sure if I overlooked something yesterday. Does spring treat directory (version1 and version2) as a profile in this scenario?

Comment: don't know havent tried that yet i have seperate repos for different  profiles so in confiserver properties file for seprate profile i read seperate repos. That way i just need to make the config server profile based and everything else can work individually. You might have to do something like that too try changing the search path for different profile if you donot want seperate repos.

Comment: Grinish - Hi , I created a client program set the value to name: app-dev-v1 and name: app-dev-v2 as you suggested. But property lookup is failing.  However if I remove -v1 and -v2 , the property is being looked up correctly. However I want to specifically fetch properties from v1 and v2 explicitly.

Comment: Please update the question with the changes you have made so that i can see what have you done. Its hard to answer if i donot know what changes you have made.

Comment: Also read this it might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671317/properties-versioning-with-spring-cloud-config