# Spring Cloud Config Server - properties not being returned

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

This question is related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554205/spring-cloud-config-versioning). The approach seemed to work earlier today but now I am seeing the below response instead of seeing the properties defined the properties file -

```
{
"name": "order-service"
"profiles": [1]
0:  "dev-v1"
-
"label": null
"version": "0299eae906ee10555b68bd1bfe36bd390728969e"
"propertySources": [0]
}
```

I see empty propertySources.

Below is what is defined in my application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.companyname.com/projectname/orderservice-properties
          username: ordersvc
          password: ordersvc
          search-paths: order-service,v*
```

The github url has 2 folders v1 and v2 which have file order-service-dev.properties.

Please can you let me know what I am missing? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I changed the application.yml to below:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.companyname.com/projectname/orderservice-properties
          username: ordersvc
          password: ordersvc
          search-paths: order-service/v*
```

Now I see the below when using endpoint http://localhost:8080/order-service/dev. How can I see specific endpoint's data (say v1 or v2)?

```
{
"name": "order-service"
"profiles": [1]
0:  "dev"
-
"label": null
"version": "693378d4145cca50e38d5b9e39afbe1a3b334c6c"
"propertySources": [2]
0:  {
"name": "https://github.companyname.com/projectname/orderservice-properties/order-service/v2/order-service-dev.properties"
"source": {
"key3": "value3"
"key2": "value2"
"key1": "value1"
}-
}-
1:  {
"name": "https://github.companyname.com/projectname/orderservice-properties/order-service/v1/order-service-dev.properties"
"source": {
"key3": "value3"
"key2": "value2"
"key1": "value1"
}
}    
}
```

Comment: I am able to see the proper response when I paste the property file under order-service folder and access using endpoint http://localhost:8080/order-service/dev. However I am still facing the same issue when I try to access the property under v1 and v2 folders using endpoint http://localhost:8080/sales-service/dev-v1 or http://localhost:8080/sales-service/dev-v2

Comment: Why are you trying to put versions in the file name? Wouldn't a branch be easier?

Comment: I am not adding versions to the file name. The file name always remains the same (eg: order-service-dev.properties). I have created the versions as directories. When version1 app requests for props , I want the file to returned from version1 directory by spring cloud config server.

Comment: How is it going to pick the right version? config server understands 3 pieces of data from a client, application name, spring profiles and label (git branch).

Comment: Isn't there a way to treat the directory as a profile. I was trying to see if the correct file will be returned when I use a url similar to "http://localhost:8080/order-service/dev-v1" or "http://localhost:8080/order-service/dev-v2".

Comment: If you are using the latest version, we support placeholders https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-config.adoc#placeholders-in-git-uri

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb! How can substitute the placeholder when I send a rest request?

Comment: Sorry spencergibb , is it possible to explain how it can be used to solve my issue? Thanks for your help.