# Properties versioning with Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring-boot, versioning, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am probably missing something here, but what is a good solution for properties versioning?

For example, in a blue-green deployment scenario with property value changes (old app version consumes the old value, new version requires the new value), how do you ensure both versions of your app can successfully co-exist (considering potential restarts and rollbacks)?

One option would be to create new property names for the properties that need new values applied. This, of course, is not a good option as we need to track all the usages of that property in the code base and update its reference accordingly. It is also not nice from a conceptual perspective.

Another option is to have a branch for each release. While this could work very well for this scenario, I envisage a branch/tag hell as we scale to the config repo to multiple apps and their respective branches evolve into different directions.

A solution to the branch hell would be to have a separated config repo for each app. But, I believe this in some sense defeats the purpose of the config server as it adds overhead.

Any other approaches?

Answer (score 13):

Spring Cloud Config's `Environment` resources are parametrized by three variables:

1. `{application}` maps to `spring.application.name` on the client side
2. `{profile}` maps to `spring.active.profiles` on the client
3. `{label}` which is a server side feature labelling a **versioned** set
   of config files.

Since in case of Blue-Green deployments, you're using the same application in the same profile, the best option is to use *Versioned* config files by using git *Tags*.

The basic idea is to create tags for different versions of config files and tell your application to use configurations related to an specific tag using `spring.cloud.config.label` in your `bootstrap.properties`.

For example, you can tag two different commits with `v1.0` and `v2.0`:

[image]

And use `spring.cloud.config.label=v1.0` for old instance and `spring.cloud.config.label=v2.0` for new instance.

> as we scale to the config repo to multiple apps and their respective
>   branches evolve into different directions.

In order to avoid this problem, I suggest to only save common and cross application properties in `application-{profile}.properties` config files. The better approach is that to each application has its own config file, e.g. `recommender.properties` for recommender service and `search.properties` for search service. Then you can use profile specific and versioned properties for each of them by defining the appropriate `spring.application.name`. This way you can achieve to some level of *Single Responsibility Principle* in your configuration files.

Comment: Above solution is specific to Git based systems. How about properties in File system/native properties?

Comment: I know this answer is old, but it still does not satisfy my needs and I feel there is a big point being missed.
Our company trying to implement the config server with a single repository to store properties for our middleware ecosystem.
If we follow this approach of using labels, we will end up with hundreds of labels each month for every time we edit a property for one of the applications. There is also the fact that no two applications can have the same version, otherwise the labels will clash.

Makes no sense to be limiting the use cases of the library for no reason.

Comment: @brenosilva Did you find a smart solution meanwhile? I'm currently facing the same issues and would like to step onto your shoulders :)